# How to check if two Facebook id are friends or not Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Hi I have user registered through facebook in my App and In mysql database I am having **facebook unique id**.
How can i get the list of my facebook friends from mysql database.
I mean using **facebook sdk compare two facebook id** and get result if they are friends or not

Answer (score 1):

You get a list of all friends (who authorized your App) with the `/me/friends` endpoint. You can also get the friends info for a specific friend like this: `/me/friends/123455` (the number is the friend id).

If you need to know if two App users are friends while they are not online, you can do two different things:

- Store an Extended User Token for each user, it is valid for 60 days and you can use the API call above to check if two users are friends.
- Store the IDs of friends (= the result of `/me/friends`) when the user authorizes your App, and update the info whenever he visits your App again. That way you don´t even need an API call, but the friends may not be up to date.

Comment: I need to check if two users are friends by passing their facebook id

Comment: i will add some more info to my answer